# Symfony2 Embedded Form Collection Not Validating

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have an entity `Company` and `Address` that have their own types `CompanyType` and `AddressType`. The `AddressType` is embedded in `CompanyType`. I did everything exactly the same as in [Embedded Forms cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). The form is embedded correctly and is showing exactly as it should but validation is not working. I use separate `.yml` files for validation like this...

```
        $yamlMappingFiles = $container->getParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files');
    $yamlMappingFiles[] = __DIR__.'/../Resources/config/validation/address_validation.yml';
    $yamlMappingFiles[] = __DIR__.'/../Resources/config/validation/company_validation.yml';
    $container->setParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files', $yamlMappingFiles);
```

... and it is not validating in any of the entities. I tried corrupting the yml files and the parser throws an error which means that it loads the files. I also tried viewing `var_dump($form->getErrors());` but it returns an empty array. At the same time, if i leave all blank fields in forms, the form isn't validated. Code is not entering here...

```
if( $form->isValid() ) {
    ... does not enter here if all input elements are empty ...
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, if no validation is used on a form, the form is always valid, so this must mean that validation `.yml` files are processed.

I didn't post any code beacuse my form is exactly the same as in the cookbook example. Just imagine that `Task` is `Company` and `Tag` is `Addres`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have not seen validation files loaded that way.  My first suggestion would be to add a few rules the standard config/validation.yml file and see if they are getting picked up.  That will isolate the problem to either the loading process or something in your form.  You could also update the question with a few lines from one of your validator files and the corresponding lines from your entity.

Comment: And I am sure you are aware that, by default, the forms system requires a value in all fields.  But that is a browser based validation.  Still you could try setting required=false in your form options.

Comment: If you thinking about HTML5 validation, I've disabled that. I've tried the same loading for validation files with embedded forms but without collections, and it worked for the parent and for the child with the added 'cascade_validation' to 'true'. I'll try the first one and see what happens.

Comment: What's the output for `$form->getErrorsAsString()` ?

Comment: It returns an empty string, nothing more. I've done some other custom stuff to validate the two entities. I'll try this one more time in a week or so, and I will post something here if I discover what was wrong.